# Can I connect 12V power input of 4 hard drives and power them from one DC adapter/brick?

Tags: hard-drive, enclosures

I want to build my own hard drive enclose and I was wondering if I can power 4 hard drives using a setup like below. There are cheap SATA to USB adapters like the ones you see below that have 12V input for 3.5" drives. Can I connect 4 of those input like below and get power without burning anything? Or do I need to connect them in a different way?

All drives I have are different models of same brand, they have similar but slightly different power draw, they all require 12V 2A power at the start. It's also stated that the ampere required can vary ±10%. I am aware I will need 12V 8A (or maybe 9A for that 10%?).

(Note that all my hard drives have both 12V and 5V written on it, but it was my understanding that 5V will simply be drawn from USB, isn't that correct?)

Link to the image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6rdrx.jpg

(I asked the same question in electrical engineering but I've been advised to ask here)

Comment: There’s no reason this wouldn’t work as long as the power supply can put out enough power to them all.

Comment: What is the source of the Power?

Comment: "was my understanding that 5V will simply be drawn from USB"  Each usb port can only handle 500ma (usb 2)-900ma (usb3). If your drive draws more than 900ma at 5v then you don't have enough.  So if your using individual USB ports for each drive, or have a **powered** usb hub then its ok.

Comment: @Moab I haven't one yet. I thought I could find an AC-DC adapter/power brick like a laptop brick with the needed V and A.